# Set a delay in loop execution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

I need to set a delay in the execution of a for loop in JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction1() {

        var list = document.getElementById('SomeList');
        var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

            setTimeout(delayLoop, 1500);
        }
    }
function delayLoop() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
```

After adding the "alert('Hello')" code to the delayLoop function, I noticed that the setTimeout function only displays the alert box after the execution of myFunction1().

How can I use setTimeout to slow down each loop through the collection of items to 1500ms?

Comment: see "sleep() in JavaScript" http://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use a callback here

```
var list = document.getElementById('SomeList');
var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');
var i = 0;

var myFunction1 = function() {
    if ( i < items.length ) {
         // Do some code with items[i]
         i++;
         setTimeout(myFunction1, 1500);
    } else { 
         // No more elements
         return;
    }
}
```

This way your `myFunction1` will execute every 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps

```
function pause(ms) {
    ms += new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms){}
}
```